# How to select the specific row that matched a specific variable in excel?

Tags: excel, perl

I got a list of variables that stored in an array. I know how to select specific columns and rows but I only want to select specific row that matched variables in array (assume all the variables is unique, only will appear in excel once). Is that possible do it and how it can be done?

Excel:

```
Name    Code    Age
John    0123    18
ean     1234    19
```

My code for now:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

@name = ("john", "tommy", "ming", "ean");

##Loop through the array and search in excel##
foreach my $test (@name) {

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('C:\namelist.xlsx');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets('Name List') ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

           **Any Idea what should I do here to get expected result?**

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Expected result: While looping through the array `@name`, it will search in the excel, if the variable like `John` is matched, it will retrieve all the data of that row and store it in variables.  EG. `$code = 01234;` and `$Age=18;`

Any related post/info/ans to share as I can't found one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code in perl :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('C:\namelist.xlsx');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
 die $parser->error(), ".\n";
     }

my @name = ("john", "tommy", "ming", "ean");   
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets('Name List') ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
        next unless $cell;

        foreach my $result (@name)
          {
            my $string = $cell->value();
             if($result =~ m/$string/i)
               {  
                    my $codeCell = $worksheet->get_cell($row,1);
                    my $ageCell  = $worksheet->get_cell($row,2);
                    print "Name : $string\t";
                   if(defined $codeCell and $codeCell->value() ne "")
                     {
                          my $code = $codeCell->value(); 
                        print "Code : $code\t"; 
                        }
                    if(defined $ageCell and $ageCell->value() ne "")
                     {
                          my $age = $ageCell->value(); 
                        print "Age : $age\n"; 
                        }                
                  }

              }
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Hi, I tested two version of your codes(I mean before you edit). The 2nd version seem good but there's incorrect when comes to result. I take a screenshot. Look at here `http://imgur.com/ILmD6nJ`.

Comment: I will have a look into that and get back to you .

Comment: Can i know whether your excel contains 3 columns which consists of Name values in first cells , Code values in second cells and Age values in third cells ? Is it the same or any difference ?

Comment: Name,Code,Age is 1st row and Name is in the 1st cell  ,code - 2nd cell  and age - 3rd cell. Is totally the same as the example I gave. Thanks!

Comment: I did not find any problem from my end as i tested it . So did you copy the entire code of mine and run the program ?

Comment: Yup, entire program. The result you get are 2 lines only right?
`Name : John    Code : 0123    Age : 18`
`Name : Ean     Code :1234     Age : 19`. The result I get is the screentshot i provided.

Comment: Yes, i got only two lines. I am surprised to see that you are getting uninitialized name values in the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63985/discussion-between-thor-that-new-in-programming-and-praveen).